# How to display a comma or semicolon separated list of values

Tags: jsf, datatable, richfaces

I have a rich faces datatable. I want to display a list of strings in a single cell as comma(or semicolon) seperated values. Is there a way in richfaces to do this?

Comment: Iterate with a `ui:repeat` through the list.

Comment: Poor question without code or anything you've tried. Wrap your List in a wrapper class and override it's `toString()` method. Then provide the wrapper class as the value in your `<h:outputText/>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use [`<ui:repeat>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/ui/repeat.html). You can use `varStatus` to reference an iteration status instance which has among others a boolean `last` property which is helpful in omitting the comma from the last item.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{listOfStrings}" var="string" varStatus="loop">
    #{string}#{not loop.last ? ', ' : ''}
</ui:repeat>
```